# Video height 100vh ignoring overflow hidden.

Tags: css, overflow

I am messing around with using 100vh to make the jumbotron and its background fill the screen of the user. I didn't have this issue when using a photo, but my client wants a video background.

I have overflow set to hidden, but the site is showing the overflow with the horizontal scroll bar. I can't figure out why it won't cut it off.

Here is my code for the jumbotron and video feature.

[Website Here](http://www.dismantledesign.com/testsite2/)

```
    #video-background { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1000;
    height: 100vh;
    }

   .jumbotron{
    font-family: 'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 60px 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
       <video id="video-background" preload muted autoplay loop>
          <source src="vid/lowres.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
    </div>
```

Obviously, there is more inside the jumbotron, but I don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overfow-x:hidden; works fine for me in chrome. I do not see any horizontal scrollbar. Try that

```
.jumbotron{
    font-family: 'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 60px 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Worked for me too, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your setting it too low, try setting on the DOM node above it, on .jumbotron, worked on chrome for me.

Comment: Also, I would probably set the width to 100vw, not the height. As the width gets cut off and video is left aligned on large screens, which looks odd. Check it out anyway, and see if that's what you want.

Comment: I thought of using 100vw, but it just doesn't give the effect I want.